# JQuery ID Attribute Script Conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have two scripts that are conflicting over an ID Attribute.  I am new to jquery although I did work quite a bit with javascript way back in the day.  Please point me in the direction of correcting the conflict whether that is rewriting the nav or rewriting the way the login modal works.

The navigation and script is from HTML5UP.. here is the code.

Navigation HTML: http://pastebin.com/Rt3x5yQX

Navigation JS: http://pastebin.com/K1xnFQQE

Modal HTML: [pastebin.com/iqEjd3qE](http://pastebin.com/iqEjd3qE)

Modal JS: [pastebin.com/rJACpVJp](http://pastebin.com/rJACpVJp)

The issue happens when I use the ID Attribute on an  tag within the Navigation, it basically breaks it; and the Modal JS needs an ID attribute for the click event.  So what do I do?  What route do I take?  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: post your code HERE

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I had two scripts running the click event on an element within the nav.  The ID tag was needed for both causing issues.  Using data- attribute and modifying the js I was able to get things up and working.